# Most efficient way to create a slide-down submenu in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a submenu which slides down from the main menu bar when hovering over a certain element. I am currently doing this using the following code:

```js
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('.navlist li a').hover( function() {
    if( $(this).attr( 'data-param' ) == "parent" )
    {
      $('#subnavbar-' + $(this).attr( 'data-slug' )).slideDown( 200 );
    }
  }, function() {
    if( $(this).attr( 'data-param' ) == "parent" )
    {
      var name = '#subnavbar-' + $(this).attr( 'data-slug' );
      setTimeout( function() {
        if( !$(name).is(':hover') )
        {
          $(name).slideUp( 200 );
        }
      }, 200 );
    }
  });
});
```

```css
a {
  color: white;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: green;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  height: 30px;
}

ul.navlist {
  list-style: none;
  text-indent: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
}

ul.navlist li {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
}

.subnavbar {
  background-color: blue;
  margin-top: 0;
  height: 20px;
  display: none;
}

ul.subnavlist {
  list-style: none;
  text-indent: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
}

ul.subnavlist li {
  display: block;
  width: 80px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar">
  <ul class="navlist">
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-param="parent" data-slug="test">Hover Here</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="subnavbar" id="subnavbar-test">
  <ul class="subnavlist">
    <li><a href="#">Subitem 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Subitem 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Subitem 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

As you can see by running the snippet; it works, but there are lots of bugs that I'm not sure what the best way to iron out are. Firstly, if the user hovers back and forth over the main menu item I don't want the event to be spammed, I could solve this problem using a `setTimeout()` and `clearTimeout()` but I'd like a better way if at all possible. Secondly, I'm not sure how best to get the subnavbar not to retract if the user has hovered over it instead of the parent menu item, how I'm doing it at the moment works, but then if the user hovers off, the navbar doesn't retract.

Comment: If I remember correctly you need to use stopPropagation(), though I'm not sure

Comment: And is it a must to use jquery? this can be easily done with just css

Comment: @AlvaroMenéndez No, it most definitely is not a must to use jQuery; I would actually prefer a CSS solution I would think!

Answer (score 1):

The efficient solution would be using just CSS. Absolutely no JQUERY required! Try this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mu2bamzm/).

HTML:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 2</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub Sub Item 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub Sub Item 2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 3</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS Code:

```
nav {
    margin: 100px auto;
    text-align: center;
}
nav ul ul {
    display: none;
}
nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
nav ul {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    display: inline-table;
    list-style: outside none none;
    padding: 0 10px;
    position: relative;
}
nav ul::after {
    clear: both;
    content: "";
    display: block;
}
nav ul li {
    float: left;
}
nav ul li:hover {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
nav ul li:hover a {
    color: #fff;
}
nav ul li a {
    color: #757575;
    display: block;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
nav ul ul {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #5f6975;
    border-radius: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
}
nav ul ul li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #575f6a;
    border-top: 1px solid #6b727c;
    float: none;
    position: relative;
}
nav ul ul li a {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}
nav ul ul li a:hover {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #4b545f;
}
nav ul ul ul {
    left: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Whilst this is a cool solution; it's not what I'm looking for as I want the sliding down `subnavbar` to displace elements below it; rather than just sit on top of everything and have drop-down lists as in your solutions. Thank you though!

Comment: If I understand correctly,  you need a slide up/down of the sub menus??

Comment: Yes, that is correct; but an entire bar (of width: 100%) needs to slide up/down, displacing elements beneath it

Answer (score 1):

as you told me better css I've made a quick **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/q6wbcefh/4/)** for you.

Of course you need to polish the style but the "working" is there.

css just:

```
    .container {
    height:30px;
    background-color:green;
    color:#fff;
}
.container > ul {position:relative;}
.container > ul li {
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:30px;
}
.container > ul >li > ul {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    background-color:blue;
    top:0px;
    z-index:-1;       
}
.container > ul > li:hover > ul {
    top:30px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
```

edited: I change the aproach and insteed of makign the transition with height I've use just top. check it out

Comment: Thanks for your solution! However; for some reason in this solution if you hover over the submenu it drops down again and it changes? The text also appears mangled (I'm using Chrome 41)? You can see a screenshot here (http://i.imgur.com/8auPvk8.png)

Comment: This is great, but is there any way to get it so it displaces the HTML elements beneath it? If you put a div underneath it, the submenus will be obscured and changing the `z-index` just puts them on top, whereas the JavaScript method actually displaces the elements underneath?

Answer (score 0):

to solve your first issue I would recommend using the jQuery plugin Hover Intent. Like the name suggests, this provides an easy way to determine if the user intends to hover over the element and avoids the possibility of spamming the animation by quickly hovering in and out of the element multiple times.

To solve your second issue, if possible, you can add a containing element around both navbar and subnavbar and use that to close the subnavbar when you leave the containing element, if the subnavbar happens to be visible.

HTML:

```
<div id="containing_element">
   <div class="navbar">
      <ul class="navlist">
         <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
         <li><a href="#" id="hoverlink">Hover Here</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="subnavbar" id="subnavbar-test">
      <ul class="subnavlist">
         <li><a href="#">Subitem 1</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Subitem 2</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Subitem 3</a></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    function hoverEnter() {
        $('#subnavbar-test').slideDown(200);
    }
    $('#hoverlink').hoverIntent( hoverEnter );
    $('#containing_element').mouseleave(function () {
        if($('#subnavbar-test').is(':visible')) {
            $('#subnavbar-test').slideUp(200);
        }               
    });
});
```

Remember to include the script for hover intent as well.